# RegEx for multiple line statements

Tags: c#, regex

I have a file which has multiple IF conditions. 
I need to save those IF conditions in database to build a logical tree.

All IF condition statements have the same format. So, I would like to build a RegEx which can extract this.

An IF condition will have the below format

```
IF CONDITION THEN
    Variable1:=Value1 Variable2:=Value2 RETURN TRUE
ENDIF     

IF CONDITION THEN
    Variable1:=Value1 Variable2:=Value2 RETURN TRUE
ENDIF
```

and so on

The CONDITION can have multiple AND, OR, NOT, () clauses. But written in a single line.

I want the regex to return the following
1. CONDITION
2. Variable1:=Value1
3. Variable2:=Value2

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the format is strictly what you said:

```
IF (.+?) THEN\R\s+(.+:=.+) (.+:=.+)\s+RETURN TRUE\RENDIF
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/pEyvHgOnYW)

Comment: Hi, Some of my conditions also have FALSE instead of TRUE. So, such conditions are not identified by this RegEx. Is it possible to change the regex to capture TRUE, FALSE? I changed the Regex as IF (.+?) THEN\n\s+(.+:=.+) (.+:=.+)\s+RETURN (TRUE|FALSE)\nENDIF But it is capturing TRUE, FALSE. I don't need to capture them.

Comment: Use a non-capture group. A non-capture group has the syntax `(?:` to start it and `)` to end it. In your case, it would leave you with: `(?:TRUE|FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
IF\s(.+?)\sTHEN\n\s+(.+?:=.+?)\s(.+?:=.+?)\s
```

Groups 1,2,3 contain what you want respectively.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/zU6oY5/1)

Answer (score 2):

The below code should do what you want.

You can use *for* loops, or add counters to *foreach* loops (which are easier to read in this case, I think) if you want to. The code that I used to access the named groups is only an example you will have to modify to get the result you want.

The following way, you can parse input text that has errors (for example new lines where you weren't expecting them, or lowercase letters), and the values will be recognized anyway.

If you are sure the structure of the input text will be constant, you may, for example, in some cases change **'\s+'** (meaning: at least one whitespace character) in the pattern to a single space.

```
string s =
    @"aaa s
    IF CONDITION1 AND 
CONDITION2 or(cond2 and not cond4) THEN
        Variable1:=Value1 Variable2:=Value2 RETURN TRUE
    ENDIF     

    IF CONDITION THEN
        Variable1:=Value1 Variable2:=Value2 Variable3:=Value3 RETURN TRUE
    ENDIF     
    fdskjh fff";
Regex rrr = new Regex(@"^if\s+(?<Condition>[0-9a-z_\s\(\)]+)then\s+((?<Action>[0-9a-z_]+:=[0-9a-z_]+)\s+)+return\s+true\s+endif", 
                RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var matches = rrr.Matches(s);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Condition: " + match.Groups["Condition"].Value);
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups["Action"].Captures)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   Action: "+ capture.Value);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Condition: CONDITION1 AND 
CONDITION2 or(cond2 and not cond4) 
   Action: Variable1:=Value1
   Action: Variable2:=Value2
Condition: CONDITION 
   Action: Variable1:=Value1
   Action: Variable2:=Value2
   Action: Variable3:=Value3
```

**Explanation:**

**RegexOptions.Multiline** - when this option is used, **'^'** means start of new line (otherwise it is start of entire text)

**RegexOptions.IgnoreCase** - use this so you don't have to worry about lowercase or uppercase letters, it makes the regex simpler. If you want it to differentiate between lowercase and uppercase letters, you'll have to remove this option and modify the pattern accordingly.

Now, the pattern itself:

```
^if\s+(?<Condition>[0-9a-z_\s\(\)]+)then\s+((?<Action>[0-9a-z_]+:=[0-9a-z_]+)\s+)+return\s+true\s+endif
```

It uses named groups, eg:

***`(?<Condition>[0-9a-z_\s\(\)]+)`*** - a group called *'Condition'*

***`(?<Action>[0-9a-z_]+:=[0-9a-z_]+)`*** - a group called *'Action'*, that can be repeated, and is inside another group (not named). This way number of 'actions' does not have to be constant.

Those groups are later accessed by *foreach* loops.